# About Finding Size in Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I write a shell script, which aims to find files in two different folders.

Folder a

a/a 10 kb

a/b 20 kb

a/c 30 kb

a/d 15 kb

Folder b

b/t 17 kb

b/y 10 kb

b/r 22 kb

b/u 10 kb

And when I run code, results must be as below;

a/a

b/y

b/u

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the output of `ls` use the `stat` command. Example

```
$ stat -c %s .bashrc
5277

$ ls -fal  .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx xx 5277 Jun 28 23:54 .bashrc
```

Comment: Actually, It seems that I have another problems in my code, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $ for the variables:

```bsh
...
cd $folder1
...
cd $folder2
```

Also, it isn't necessary to enter to each directory. You could just pass the path to the `ls` command:

```
ls -l $folder1|grep '^-'|awk '{if(a[$5]){ a[$5]=a[$5]"\n"$NF; b[$5]++;} else a[$5]=$NF} END{for(x in b)print a[x];}'
```